# How 85% video is still playable?

Tags: video, bittorrent

I am downloading video in torrents, now it is 85% downloaded, I accidentally clicked video, it played very well, but stucks after playing few mins. Why video played well even it is 85%?

Comment: Video files are a container, so as long as the container format is recognized and valid, and the beginning of the internal stream is present, it will play. Note that many torrent clients prioritize the beginning and end of files within the torrent over the bytes in the middle, and usually torrents work with fixed sized blocks (2MB IIRC) so if you have the front of the stream, you have enough of it to get started, even if it bombs out 13 seconds in.

Comment: Your torrent client may even have options for controlling this -- check out related SU question: [How to preview unfinished torrent video files](http://superuser.com/questions/111405/how-to-preview-unfinished-torrent-video-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the format of the video, the videofile, is a stream. As long as the header is in tact, the data part, which is only the stream, will then be played back correctly until missing data is found. Its likely that there's a gap not downloaded yet after a few minutes in the video.

MPEG streams are like this, which is why it is also possible to do this with MP3 files.